# Multiprocessing Manager().dict() update failed

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I tried to update a `Manager().dict` like this

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def f(d):
    print(d)
    d['a'][1] = 'something new'
    print(d)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()

    d = manager.dict()
    d['a'] = {1: 3}

    print(d)

    p1 = Process(target=f, args=(d,))

    p1.start()
    p1.join()

    print(d)
```

However, it prints

```
{'a': {1: 3}}
{'a': {1: 3}}
{'a': {1: 3}}
{'a': {1: 3}}
```

I tried to `d['a'] = Manager().dict({1: 3})`, it can print the expected outputs, but this workaround is very unefficient when the dict is very complex.

How can I make it easy to update the `Manager().dict` like normal `dict` does?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in python https://bugs.python.org/issue6766 where you cannot modify a nested dict `d['a'] = {1: 'something new'}` works in `f(d)` though

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Yeah, this is a nasty bug.

Answer (score 2):

You're not really updating the `Manager.dict`, but a regular `dict` inside it and this won't propagate.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects):

> If standard (non-proxy) list or dict objects are contained in a
>   referent, modifications to those mutable values will not be propagated
>   through the manager because the proxy has no way of knowing when the
>   values contained within are modified. However, storing a value in a
>   container proxy (which triggers a **setitem** on the proxy object)
>   does propagate through the manager and so to effectively modify such
>   an item, one could re-assign the modified value to the container
>   proxy...

So re-assigning a modified nested, regular `dict` will do the trick:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, current_process


def f(d):
    print(f"{current_process().name}: {d}")
    a = d['a']
    a[1] = 'something new'
    d['a'] = a
    print(f"{current_process().name}: {d}")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with Manager() as m:
        d = m.dict()
        d['a'] = {1: 3}    
        print(f"{current_process().name}: {d}")

        p1 = Process(target=f, args=(d,))    
        p1.start()
        p1.join()

        # convert to regular dictionary before shutting down the
        # manager-process
        d = dict(d)

    print(f"{current_process().name}: {d}")
```

Output:

```
MainProcess: {'a': {1: 3}}
Process-2: {'a': {1: 3}}
Process-2: {'a': {1: 'something new'}}
MainProcess: {'a': {1: 'something new'}}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

For Python 3.6+ it's also possible to nest proxies:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, current_process
from multiprocessing.managers import DictProxy


def f(d):
    print(f"{current_process().name}: {unproxy_dict(d)}")
    d['a'][1] = 'something new'
    print(f"{current_process().name}: {unproxy_dict(d)}")


def unproxy_dict(dict_proxy):
    return {k: (dict(v) if isinstance(v, DictProxy) else v)
            for k, v in dict_proxy.items()}


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with Manager() as m:
        d = m.dict()
        d['a'] = m.dict({1: 3})  # nested Manager.dict
        print(f"{current_process().name}: {unproxy_dict(d)}")

        p1 = Process(target=f, args=(d,))    
        p1.start()
        p1.join()

        # convert to regular dictionaries before shutting down the
        # manager-process
        d = unproxy_dict(d)

    print(f"{current_process().name}: {d}")
```

Comment: So we still should nest the `DictProxy` or create `Manager().dict()` to avoid this bug? Right? If the one instance of `Manager().dict()` calls `.clear()`, will it free the memory?

Comment: @GoingMyWay Yes, you can use any of the both approaches like shown in the two code snippets. `.clear()` should free memory eventually (gc) if you don't hold any other references to the nested objects. Remember that containers in Python only hold references to other objects, not the actual values.

Comment: Thank you. I tried `d['a'] = m.dict({1: [1, 2]})` and do `d['a'][1] = 'new value` in `f`, still, cannot change the value, So I think I need to use a nested `Manager().list()`.

Comment: @GoingMyWay If you intend to exchange `[1, 2]` for `new value` you could also do it with `a = d['a']; a[1] = 'something new'; d['a'] = a`. Only the first dictionary would be a manager-dict, like in the first example. Result would be `{'a': {1: 'something new'}}`.